# Running jQuery ajax function when user clicks the back or forward buttons

Tags: jquery

I have the following example where when a user clicks a navigation line it loads in some content using AJAX and also updates the url and title using the jquery history.js https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/ plugin to do some HTML5 History.

```
 ajaxNav: function () {

        $('#uiTabs li a, .ajax').live('click', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $('<div id="uiLoader"></div>').appendTo('body').hide().fadeIn();

            var url = $(this).attr('href');

            var bodyid = $(this).data('body');

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function (responseHtml) {

                    isAjaxNav = true;

                    var content = $(responseHtml).find('#ajax-nav-html');

                    $('.uiContent > .uiPadding').html(content.hide().fadeIn('slow'));

                    History.pushState(null, $(responseHtml).filter('title').text(), url);

                    $('body').attr('id', bodyid);
                    $('#uiLoader').fadeOut(function () { $('#uiLoader').remove() });

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
                        uiModal.errorTimeoutModal(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == "500") {
                        uiModal.error500Modal(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == "404") {
                        uiModal.error404Modal(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    } else {
                        uiModal.errorUnknownModal(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }

                    $('#uiLoader').fadeOut(function () { $('#uiLoader').remove() });

                }
            });

        });

    },
```

However when a user clicks the back or forth buttons it will change the url and title (as the plugin supports this fine) but the content will not change! How would I detect this so that I can read the new url using for example `$('location').att('pathname');` then do some more ajax?

So for example:

```
//IF back button or forward button clicked or relevant function e.g backspace
$(<!-- ? -->).click(function() {

// Get the current url when the back or forward button was clicked
var url = $('location').att('pathname');

$.ajax({
                url: url,
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function (responseHtml) {

                    isAjaxNav = true;

                    var content = $(responseHtml).find('#ajax-nav-html');

                    $('.uiContent > .uiPadding').html(content.hide().fadeIn('slow'));

                    History.pushState(null, $(responseHtml).filter('title').text(), url);

                    $('body').attr('id', bodyid);
                    $('#uiLoader').fadeOut(function () { $('#uiLoader').remove() });

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
                        uiModal.errorTimeoutModal(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == "500") {
                        uiModal.error500Modal(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == "404") {
                        uiModal.error404Modal(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    } else {
                        uiModal.errorUnknownModal(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }

                    $('#uiLoader').fadeOut(function () { $('#uiLoader').remove() });

                }
            });
});
```

Comment: You are not showing effort but, unfortunatelly, I cannot downvote you as you did to me. The answer lies within history.js. Read it's documentation again. The author provides a full comentated version.

Comment: Really? Can you show a link as I have looked at the documentation and I don't see anything about handling this... I have seen the `History.back()` function but that ISN'T what I need here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to attach to the `window.onpopstate` event:

```
$(window).on("popstate", function (evt) { // use bind() for jQuery < 1.7
    /* ... */
});
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/CZwQB/** (uses DOM methods instead of jQuery)

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate

Comment: Also when the state changes how would it know what to change? as I have other ajax calls on the page that would also be classed as statechange so it would call the function when not needed! and also call it when the first function I posted is called. So we'd end up calling the ajax twice and when ever any state changes!

Comment: @Cameron: you can do it by parsing the current URL in the `popstate` event handler, or you can push data returned by your previous AJAX calls when you call `pushState` and reparse it in the `popstate` event by accessing `event.state`.

Comment: @Cameron: I don't have enough time to write an AJAX example, but I can assure you it's not too different from the example I just added to my post.  As long as you pass your AJAX data to `pushState()`, it should work very similarly.

Comment: Thanks for the example but the problem is that the function runs straight away and not ONLY when a user clicks the back or forth buttons.

Comment: @Cameron: are you talking about my example, or your code? In my example, you can prevent that by removing the part that checks the `window.location.search` stuff near the top of the code.

Comment: Well popstate looks for a statechange rather than a back or forth change so basically if an ajax call happens it will run the code. So if I do a call it will run the original ajax and then the popstate! But popstate also runs on load of the page e.g.         window.onpopstate = function (evt) {

            alert('moo');
        } will show moo on postback?

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/CZwQB/1/ it shows the alert straight away so it's not looking for back or forth.

Comment: See the updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/CZwQB/1 see the alert fires straight away!

Comment: @Cameron: that *shouldn't* happen, but you can fix it by adding `if (!event.state) return;` to the code —  http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/CZwQB/2/.  Note that only WebKit seems to do this, Firefox and IE 10 don't appear to have that problem.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong.  According to a bug filed on Chromium, their behaviour is correct and `onpopstate` *should* fire on page load.  The fix still applies, though.

Comment: I've [moved this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4884/discussion-between-andy-e-and-cameron) in an effort to tidy things up here.