# jQuery back or forth button

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to catch the back button event in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136937/is-there-a-way-to-catch-the-back-button-event-in-javascript)

How can I detect a back or forth button click?

e.g.

```
if(back_button_clicked)
{
    alert('back button was clicked');
}
else if(forward_button_clicked)
{
    alert('forwardbutton was clicked');
}
```

As I want to run some special functions when the user does this.

Comment: You have just asked the same question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080151/running-jquery-ajax-function-when-user-clicks-the-back-or-forward-buttons

Comment: Not the same question! The other is related to ajax!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Browser buttons like back and forward are not revealed to Javascript. You could use JQuery's `unload()` event to run code when the user leaves the page, that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery plugin -

http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/

Comment: I'm already using a history plugin! What I need to do is run some function when a user clicks one of those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the unload event of the window :

```
$(window).unload( function () { alert("Bye now!"); } );
```

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)

But this wont tell you the direction - is this important ?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onpopstate = function (evt) {
    if (event.state) {
        alert('back or forth clicked');
    }
}
```

Comment: Only a handful of browsers support the History APIs (pushState, and onpopstate)

Comment: This looks like you plagiarized [Andy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080151/running-jquery-ajax-function-when-user-clicks-the-back-or-forward-buttons/8080184#8080184) from your duplicate question.

Comment: I would hardly call it plagarism! Rather showing the answer to the question and it wasn't a duplicate question rather an answer that solves both problems!